# Accumulate messages for each client in Socket.io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, data-structures, socket.io

I have a server and need a connection of 4 clients and have problem in this part, because just cas connect one client the client stops automatically in the smarthphone. Work fine with 1 client.

I would like to store the data for each client in an array and display that data in a string like this:

```
"0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0# 0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0# 0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0# 0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#"
```

The array for each client should contain all the messages emitted to that client. Unfortunately, I get only one message per client which looks like this:

```
"0#0.0 0.0 3593.0#3#0.0#"
```

I would like to know how to accumulate the data for each client in an array or object.

This is my current approach:

Server code:

```
var map = {};

function storeInfo(event, value){
    map[event]= value;
}
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var clientPlayer = null;
  socket.on('message', function(data) {
    var sessionid = socket.id;
    if(sessionid in map){
      map[sessionid] = data;
      var result = [];
      for(var o in map){
        result.push(map[o]);
      }
      result.join(" ");
      socket.broadcast.emit('message', result);
    } else {
      storeInfo(sessionid, data);
    }
      socket.emit('message', data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` object should store data in an array for each socket's id like you suggested. You can define the `storeInfo` function in this form:

```
function storeInfo(event, value){
    if(map[event]) {
      map[event].push(value);
    } else {
      // Initialize the value of each key as an array.
      map[event] = [];
      map[event].push(value);
    }
}
```

You can then use it this way:

```
socket.on('message', function(data) {
  var sessionid = socket.id;
  storeInfo(sessionid, data);

  var result = [];
  for (var key in map) {
    result.push(map[key].join(' '));
  }
  result.join("\n");
  socket.broadcast.emit('message', result);
  socket.emit('message', data);
});
```

Comment: the give a bucle first ["0#0.0 0.0 256.5#3#0.0#"] after ["0#0.0 0.0 256.5#3#0.0# 0#0.0 0.0 509.5#3#0.0#"] after ["0#0.0 0.0 256.5#3#0.0# 0#0.0 0.0 509.5#3#0.0# 0#0.0 0.0 760.0#3#0.0#"] for 1 client.